# How to distinguish between UIAlertView Cancel and UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput's TextView Return?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitextfield, uialertview

I have created a `UIAlertView`

```
alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test"
                                   message:@"Working"
                                  delegate:self
                         cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                         otherButtonTitles:nil];

[alert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput]; 
alert.tag = kAlertTypePIN;

UITextField *textField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
textField.delegate = self;
```

If I press Retun key in `UIAlertView` textfield it works fine, it calls:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
   [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
```

and then

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
  NSLog(@"didDismissWithButtonIndex");
  // If no text or wrong text show alert again otherwise normal actions
}
```

But if I press the cancel button, it 1st calls `textFieldDidEndEditing` which in turn calls the alert delegate. And again it calls the alert delegate method by itself.

So alert to be displayed is not getting shown and keyboard starts to pop up and goes back. So no alert is being shown in case when its to be shown.

If any doubts in the flow, please ask me.

How can I rectify the issue?

Answer (score 1):

unset the delegate of the textField in `alertView:willDismissWithButtonIndex:`

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    UITextField *textField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
    textField.delegate = nil;
}
```

When the alert is dismissed the textField will end editing, and afterwards it will call the `textFieldDidEndEditing:` delegate method.
If you set the delegate to nil before the dismissal starts, the delegate method can't be called.

Besides that, a better design would be to have a cancel button **"Cancel"**, and an other button **"Submit"**. When the `textField` ends you dismiss the alert with **"Submit"**, and not **"Cancel"**.

Answer (score 0):

You simply want to hide `UIAlertiView` on cancel click?

Then if your cancel `buttonindex` is 1 then:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;

    if(buttonIndex == 1) {
        [[alert textFieldAtIndex:0] resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this condition.. as you dont want alert to be gone when Pin is not there...

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
    {
       if([textField.text length]!=0)
         [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide UIAlertiView on "Cancel" button click then just simply add this code to clickedButtonAtIndex:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
     if(buttonIndex == 1)
     {
          [[alert textFieldAtIndex:0] resignFirstResponder];
     } 
}
```

Comment: Nope. I have two flows. Both flows should go into the code present in didDismissWithButtonIndex function. There I checks whether the text entered is invalid or zero length and if so I will fire the same alert again. 
One flow is working perfectly - when I click the Return button of the alertview's textfield.
2nd flow is not working - when I press the Cancel button in AlertView. It calls endEditing 1st and then alert view's delegate.

Comment: if so then you should set alert's delegate to be nil while you click on cancel button. So it will not allow to go for second time in alert view's delegate.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

Add UIAlertView following delegate method

`- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;`

`{`

`[[alert textFieldAtIndex:0] resignFirstResponder];`

`}`